# Doubt regarding unboundedness of complex valued polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we provide a completely rigorous proof that any complex valued polynomial, say $\mathcal{P}(z)$, is unbounded ?

Can you kindly provide some inequality, if needed, which can be used to prove this fact ? The proofs i have seen mostly relied upon some sort of intuition involving $\lvert z \rvert$ being arbitrarily large, to prove that  $\mathcal{P}(z)$ is unbounded ?

Comment: Can you first prove that $1/z\to 0$ as $z\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes. $z \to \infty \implies \lvert z \rvert \to \infty \implies \lvert \frac{1}{z} \rvert \to 0 \implies  \frac{1}{z} \to 0$. How should I proceed from there ?

Comment: Ok so that implies by the product rule for limits that if $m\geq 1$, then $1/z^m\to 0$ as well. Now given a polynomial $P(z)=a_nz^n+\dots +a_0$, with $n\geq 1$ and $a_n\neq 0$, factor out the largest power $z^n$. What can you say about the limit of the remaining junk?

Comment: Okay ! By your reasoning, the total limit will be $(\to \infty) times 1$, which is $\infty$, and the first implication in my previous comment will complete the proof. Thank you @peek-a-boo.

Comment: not times $1$, but times $a_n\neq 0$.